# How to list all the parameter values using Matlab function

Tags: matlab, parameters

I am trying to list all the parameter values from the model (simulink) by using matlab function.
To identify constant values, I have used the function;
`Block=find_system(ModelName,'LookUnderMasks','on','FollowLinks','on','BlockType','Constant');` 
To identify 1D and 2D map, I have used the following function respectively;
`1D=find_system(ModelName,'LookUnderMasks','on','FollowLinks','on','FunctionName','put_calmap1d'); 2D=find_system(ModelName,'LookUnderMasks','on','FollowLinks','on','FunctionName','put_calmap2d');`

But there may be other blocks with parameter values, such as put_FaultCheck (S-function), put_SlewRateCheck....

is there any method, where I can identify all the parameter values in a simulink and list them on a table using Matlab function

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you are browsing parameters it would be easier to use model explorer and look at blocks and their dialogs hierarchically.

Comment: Hi @Navan , thank you for your comment, well I have a very complicated model and it takes time to find all the parameters manually, so to save time I'm trying to build a matlab code which could generate all the parameters of the model and I could identify it easily.

Comment: You would need to do this by first finding all blocks in the model. Then for each block you can get list of dialog parameters by getting 'DialogParameters'. In that list you need to get string type parameters and check whether the entered value is a variable name or numeric.